# In Java, if a method uses a static member, why should itself be declared as static?

Tags: java

I understand that in a static method, non-static members should be called with related objects, or there would be ambiguity.

If my understand is correct?

Comment: Are you asking about accessing a static member or a non static member? Your title and question body seem to ask different things.

Comment: It shouldn't necessarily be declared static: it is entirely up to you.

Comment: Wrong title and body of problem!

Comment: Do you understand what `static` means? See [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: It's really unclear what this question is asking, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

> In Java, if a method uses a static member, why should itself be declared as static?

This is not true - a method that uses a `static` member does not need to be `static` itself.

> I understand that in a static method, non-static members should be called with related objects, or there would be ambiguity.
>
> If my understand is correct?

No.

When a member variable or method is `static`, it means that this member variable or method isn't part of, or doesn't work on one specific object of the class; it's shared by all objects of the class. The section [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials explains this in more detail.

Non-static methods work on a specific object, so if you call them from a static method, you have to call them on an object, since there is no current object (which `this` refers to) when you're in a static method.